# Credit for a sports license

Tags: faa-regulations

As a new CFII, I have a student who has about 250 hours in a Czech Sport plane, lots of cross-country time, etc. He also already has about 40 hours in a C172 going back 12 years.  Looking at the requirements for a PPL, how much of that SPL time will count?  Seems to me, once he's comfortable in our C172 and completes his night requirements, he's got all the other requirements??  Am I right?

Comment: was their instruction time from a CFI or a CFI-S?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the hours count, assuming your student has already earned the SPL. From part 61.109(l):

> The holder of a sport pilot certificate may credit flight training received from a flight instructor with a sport pilot rating toward the aeronautical experience requirements of this section if the following conditions are met:
>
> (1) The flight training was accomplished in the same category and class of aircraft for which the rating is sought;
>
> (2) The flight instructor with a sport pilot rating was authorized to provide the flight training; and
>
> (3) The flight training included either -
>
> (i) Training on areas of operation that are required for both a sport pilot certificate and a private pilot certificate; or
>
> (ii) For airplanes with a $\text V^H$ greater than 87 knots CAS, training on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to the flight instruments, including straight and level flight, turns, descents, climbs, use of radio aids, and ATC directives, provided the training was received from a flight instructor with a sport pilot rating who holds an endorsement required by § 61.412(c).

SPL students do not usually receive instrument training, and if they have the instrument hours only count if they were given in accordance with 61.109(l)(3)(ii). SPL students do not receive any night training so you will have to provide those. Finally, you will need to provide them with the required 3 hours of checkride preparation within two months of the checkride.

If your student received their previous training from a CFI instead of a CFI-S, then they can count everything regardless of whether they actually earned their SPL or not. It's still likely they did not receive instrument or night training, so you will still need to provide those.

Comment: All training was done with a CFII, appreciate the help, that’s about what I came up with also.